# How do I count the number of times each alphabet occurs in a string without using collection types?

Tags: python, string, loops, count, find

As the title suggests, I'm doing a python assignment where the question requires me to count the number of times each alphabet occurs in a string without using collection types?

For example:

ID='AAAABBBCCD'

The print result should result in '4A 3B 2C 1D'.

What I've tried so far:

```
def count_occurence(ID, to_find):
    number = 0
    for x in range(len(ID)):
        if ID[x] == to_find:
            number +=1
    return number

ID=(input("Enter ID: "))
first_check = count_occurence(ID,'A')
second_check = count_occurence(ID,'B')
print(first_check,second_check)
```

But I don't think it's efficient, as I would have to create a check all the way from 'A' to 'Z'.

Note: The collection types are set, list and dict.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you include lists in the collection types?

Comment: I've made some edits to clarify things.

Comment: if ID='AAAABBBCCDAACB', then the result is?

Answer (score 0):

```
ID='AAAABBBCCD'
n = 0
verify = []
output = ''
for i in ID:
    count = 0
    char = ID[n]
    if not char in verify  :
        verify.append(char)
        for z in range(len(ID)):
            if char == ID[z]:
                count += 1

        output +=' ' + str(count) + char

    n += 1
print(output)
```

Comment: please remember to always comment and explain the code in your answers, please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer/

Comment: I'm a python noob, may I ask for some explanations please?

Comment: Sure, what do you wanna know?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using `eval` and `exec`.

here is the code:

```
def count_str(id_str):
    for i in range(65, 65 + 26):
        exec("var_" + chr(i) + " = 0")
    for c in id_str:
        exec("var_" + c + " = " + "var_" + c + " + 1")
    rtn_str = ""
    for i in range(65, 65 + 26):
        if eval("var_" + chr(i) + " > 0"):
            rtn_str = rtn_str + str(eval("var_" + chr(i))) + chr(i) + " "
    if(len(rtn_str) >0):
        rtn_str = rtn_str[0: -1]
    return rtn_str
```

test：

```
>>> count_str("AAAABBBCCD")
'4A 3B 2C 1D'
>>> count_str("AAAABBBCCDAB")
'5A 4B 2C 1D'
>>> count_str("AAAABBBCCDABEEFG")
'5A 4B 2C 1D 2E 1F 1G'
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the comments inside code for explanation

```py
ID='AAAABBBCCD'

# create an empty dictionary
output = {}

# iterate over the string ID
for each_alphabet in ID:
    # check whether it exists in output dictionary
    if each_alphabet in output.keys():
        output[each_alphabet] += 1 # increment the value to 1
    else:
        output[each_alphabet] = 1

# finally generate the result
final_result = ' '.join([f'{v}{k}' for k,v in output.items()])

print(final_result)
```

```
4A 3B 2C 1D
```